# How to parse a CSV with JSON fields containing separator?

Tags: java, json, csv, univocity

I have the following CSV file with a JSON field that may contains the separator:

```
2.0.0|2018-11-04 10:10:14,471|eventname|{"fieldA":"value with separator | inside","fieldB":"54321"}|123456|empty
```

I tried to use the following code to get the whole field but it is always get split by the inner separator:

```
String csvLine = "2.0.0|2018-11-04 10:10:14,471|eventname|{\"fieldA\":\"value with separator | inside\",\"fieldB\":\"54321\"}|123456|empty"; 

CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setDelimiter("|");
settings.getFormat().setQuote('"');
settings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape('\\');

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

String[] row = parser.parseLine(csvLine);
System.out.println(row[3]);
```

Expected output:

```
{"fieldA":"value with separator | inside","fieldB":"54321"}
```

Current output:

```
{"fieldA":"value with separator
```

How can I tell the CSV parser to not split when the file is between quotes?

Comment: That CSV file is corrupt, since it didn't quote / escape the value containing a separator character. Don't try to parse it. Fix the code creating the file instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the file write. I have to read them in this exact format.

Comment: Then fix the line, by changing `|` to ``\|`` if the number of preceding ``\"`` is odd.

Comment: *FYI:* If the line contains ``\"``, then you need to write ``String csvLine = "2.0.0|2018-11-04 10:10:14,471|eventname|{\\"fieldA\\":\\"value with separator | inside\\",\\"fieldB\\":\\"54321\\"}|123456|";``

Comment: Since the format is always the same you can exploit the spaces between the separator in the JSON: replace `" | "` (space | space) with a string, say `_NONSEP_`, then split the CSV, finally replace `_NONSEP_` in the JSON with the `" | "` again. This is dirty but so is your format. At least this way is easy. Hope this helps.